# Restrict Pages/URLs to Admin only in Flask

Tags: python, flask

In GAE, restrict certain urls to Admin only is [quite easy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig):

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin
```

Now I am using Flask. I have to repeat the same code in every admin only function to tell if a user is admin, which makes the code long and redundant.

```
@app.route('/admin/somepage')
def AdminPage():
   #Figure out if a user is admin
```

Is there some better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`app.before_request()` hook](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqcontext/?highlight=before_request#callbacks-and-errors) to inspect the request and respond with a redirect when the requested path starts with `/admin/` but authentication information is missing or insufficient.

```
def check_for_admin(*args, **kw):
    if request.path.startswith('/admin/'):
        if not user.is_admin():
            return redirect(url_for('login_form'))
```

By returning a response object (such as produced by the [`flask.redirect()` function](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.redirect) from a `before_request` handler stops processing and the actual view is not invoked.

You can also use a decorator to mark admin views; this is more flexible (routes don't need to be all under one path) and more discoverable (each route has the decorator on it).

Comment: I prefer the decorator way.

Answer (score 0):

your AdminPage() should be a class inheriting from flask_admin BaseView, and you override the method is_accessible, like this:

```
from flask_admin import BaseView

class AdminPage(BaseView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user_is_admin()

    @expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def do_whatever(self):
        # do it
        return self.render("admin/whatever.html")
```

of course, your user class need to have a method (in the example it's called current_user_is_admin()) which evaluates True only if the current user is an administrator. You need to have this information anyway, regardless the way you implement this.

This is the proper way to use flask_admin, as far as I understand. You can define as complex, or as simple, permission rules as you like, per every admin function, just by changing the is_accessible() override.